# USB device turns off - relay switch does not restart it - unplugging and re-plugging does. What is the difference?

Tags: usb, serial

I have a USB to serial converter which the Raspberry Pi 3B seems to turn off after a few hours.  LSUSB shows it is gone, and then it can be restarted by unplugging and then re-plugging the device into the USB port.  So I thought I would add a switch (using relays) to the device to simulate re-plugging.  I can then control the relays with a GPIO pin.

I built a relay board (four relays) to switch the USB device off and on which works (all four USB lines) until the PI turns it off after a few hours.  Then switching the relays has no effect, but physically unplugging and re-plugging does.  What I mean is I can switch the relays on and off and LSUSB shows the device is present when the relays are on, and not present when the relays are off.  But when I check later and find the the PI has quit "seeing" the USB device, switching the relays does nothing, but physically re-plugging the device does bring it back.

What is the difference between switching off the USB device and physically plugging it in?  Is there some order in which the USB connectors have to be activated?  Why do the relays work until the PI quits seeing the USB device?

What can I do to keep the USB device "active" - I need it to run continuously for a data acquisition project.  This is an unexpected and difficult problem.  Everything works for hours, then stops and I need a workaround or solution to fix the USB port.

So I really have two questions:  1) What is the difference between switching off the USB port connections and physically re-plugging the device?  and 2)  Why does the PI quit seeing the device on USB0 and what can I do about it?  All the other USB devices (mouse, keyboard, memory sticks, hubs) stay on.

Let me know what other information you need me to supply.

Thanks!

Additional comments:

I am running the USB-serial device through a powered hub.

I need more than one serial device, so using the TTY pins on GPIO is not a solution.

This is the dmesg dump:

[75415.138714] usb 1-1.2.4: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0 [75418.520412] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -32 [75418.521780] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_get_line_request - failed: -32 [77131.791811] pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32 [77131.791857] pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_read_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32 [77131.932897] pl2303 ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32 [77131.947082] usb 1-1.2-port4: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
Aug 12 at 19:07
[77131.947167] usb 1-1.2.4: USB disconnect, device number 87 [77131.947575] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303_set_control_lines - failed: -19 [77131.947597] pl2303 ttyUSB0: error sending break = -19 [77131.948071] pl2303 ttyUSB0: pl2303 converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0 [77131.948152] pl2303 1-1.2.4:1.0: device disconnected

And then on relay activation:

[77229.338096] usb 1-1.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? [77230.278105] usb 1-1.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? [77230.278198] usb 1-1.2-port4: attempt power cycle [77421.595950] usb 1-1.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? [77422.535924] usb 1-1.2-port4: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad? [77422.536020] usb 1-1.2-port4: attempt power cycle

After physically re-plugging, the device comes back ok.  Still running through the relay board with no changes.

Comment: does the serial device have enough power?

Comment: if this is urgent can you try using the 3.3v serial connection over GPIO?

Comment: Your comments are unreadable. I don't read them. If you like to get an answer you should follow the suggestion of *Milliways*: put the comments into the question.

Comment: OK, I have edited and updated my question, and removed comments.